# Linq-to-SQL using int? with a null value

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm having some problems with a Linq-to-SQL query

Now if I run this request, everything run just fine and I get the right results back (2 rows).

```
return _repository.GetMenus()
                .Where(x => x.ParentId == null && x.WikiId == 1)
                .ToList();
```

But if I do the following, I just get an empty list.

```
var menu = new WikiMenu();
menu.ParentId = null;
return  _repository.GetMenus()
                   .Where(x => x.ParentId == menu.ParentId && x.WikiId == 1)
                   .ToList();
```

But if `menu.ParentId` is anything else then null it does work just fine.

This is the model WikiMenu

```
public class WikiMenu
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public int WikiId { get; set; }
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public List<WikiMenu> SubMenu { get; set; }
}
```

How can I fix this?

So far have I done this little hack

```
if(menu.ParentId == null)
     return _repository.GetMenus()
                       .Where(x => x.ParentId == null && x.WikiId == site.Id)
                       .ToList();
else
     return _repository.GetMenus()
                       .Where(x => x.ParentId == menu.ParentId && x.WikiId == site.Id)
                       .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use the following code:

```
return _repository.GetMenus().  
    Where(x => object.Equals(x.ParentId, menu.ParentId) && x.WikiId == 1).ToList();
```

This code snippet will force Linq2SQL to generate something like
`WHERE [table0].[parentId] IS NULL` rather than `WHERE [table0].[parentId] == NULL`.

Hope this helps.